# Functions not doing anything

Tags: function, unity-game-engine

I have a gameObject called BounceBack that is supposed to bounce the ball back far away when they collide together.

```
public class BounceBack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;
    public float force;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag(Player.tag))
        {
            Player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().ForceBack(force);
        }
    }
}
```

The ball Player (ball) script:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int acceleration;
    public int speedLimit;
    public int sideSpeed;

    public Text countText;
    public Text winText;

    public GameObject pickUp;
    public GameObject finishLine;

    //internal void ForceBack() //Not sure what it does and why it's there.
    //{
    //    throw new NotImplementedException();
    //}

    private int count;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        SetCount();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * sideSpeed * rb.velocity.magnitude / acceleration;
        //float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * acceleration;

        if (rb.velocity.magnitude <= speedLimit)
        {
            rb.AddForce(0.0f, 0.0f, acceleration); // add vertical force
        }
        rb.AddForce(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, 0.0f); // add horizontal force
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag(pickUp.tag))
        {
            other.GetComponent<Rotate>().Disapear();
            count++;
            SetCount();
        }
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag(finishLine.tag))
        {
            acceleration = 0;
            sideSpeed = 0;
            finishLine.GetComponent<GameEnd>().FadeOut();
            if (count >= 2)
            {
                winText.GetComponent<WinTextFadeIn>().FadeIn("Vous avez remporté la partie!");
            }
            else
            {
                winText.GetComponent<WinTextFadeIn>().FadeIn("Vous avez perdu. Réesayer?");
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetCount()
    {
        countText.text = "Count : " + count.ToString();
    }

    public void ForceBack(float force)
    {
        Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.AddForce(0.0f, 0.0f, -force, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        Debug.Log("Pass");
    }
}
```

The **AddForce** function does not do anything. I tried with **setActive(false)** and it's not working either. The only thing that works is **Debug.Log()**. I'm not sure if the speedlimit and acceleration are interfering with the function.

EDIT: I'm not sure if the problem is from Unity but I can't access any variable of the class from the forceBack function inside the class.

EDIT2: I also tried to call the AddForce function directly in the Bounce Back script but it's not working either.

```
Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0.0f, 0.0f, -force, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```

[Player (Ball) Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwF7V.png)

[Bounce Back Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbUcL.png)

Comment: Have you attempted to use the physics material to determine how something should bounce?

Comment: Your `PlayerController` script has a "Speed Limit" and "Acceleration" property in the inspector leading me to believe it's handling movement.  Is it doing anything that could interfere with setting the velocity of the RigidBody?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't bounce enough

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I posted the whole code

Answer (score 1):

So, a couple things:

1.) The physics system should already cause the ball to bounce if you've set up the colliders and rigidbodies properly.  You should only need to do something like this if the ball should gain momentum when it bounces, which is unlikely.  You should post screenshots of their inspectors if this answer doesn't help.

2.) On your rb.AddForce() call, you're applying a force in world-space, which may be the wrong direction to bounce.  If you know the ball is oriented the way it's moving, then you can call AddRelativeForce with the same parameters.  If the ball's orientation is not controlled, then you need to calculate the correct world-space direction to use before applying the force.

3.) Finally, just to confirm, the objects with BounceBack attached do have a non-zero value in the 'force' parameter in the inspector, right?

Comment: 1) If you are talking about the physics material, I have already applied one but the bounciness is not high enough.
2) Thank you for the notice
3) Yes I tried every values, in the inspector also

Comment: Okay, post screenshots of the inspector panel for the player object and one of the bounceback objects, please.

Comment: I uploaded the screenshots

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see anything in what's provided that would cause the issue.  Can you try removing any custom physics materials?  They're one of the few things I can't see at all above.